# spark mongo-connector can't read from DocumentDB

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-documentdb, mongo-connector

When i want to show my spark dataframe after:

`dataFrame = spark.read.format("mongodb").option("spark.mongodb.database","testdb").option("spark.mongodb.collection", "collection1").load()`

dataFrame.show()

It gives the following error:

`Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o83.showString. : com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.exceptions.MongoSparkException: Partitioning failed. Partitioner calling collStats command failed`

But dataFrame.printSchema() gives the result with the schema, i already find out that the collStats is not supported on DocDB, but how can i turn this function off with the mongo-connector for spark

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a view, you should try using a different partitioner than the default one.

partitioner avaible : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/batch-mode/batch-read-config/#partitioner-configurations

In my base, i can read view by using PaginateIntoPartitionsPartitioner or SinglePartitionPartitioner